# How do I get the nativescript framework to work in Xcode IDE

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

Is there any way to get the nativescript framework to work in the Xcode IDE (the gui part)? Something that would allow me to do the equivalent of `tns build ios` but in the IDE. I just need to be able to edit some of the build settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, open the `your_app/platforms/ios/your_app_name.xcworkspace` with xcode and there you have all the option to change the build settings and build/run your app.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but when i built it, it spat out 3 errors and a whole bunch of warnings. Most of the warnings were about ios deployment version, but 1 error said "Unexpected duplicate tasks:" and then the path to the nativescript framework. The other two errors were both "Multiple commands produce", the path to the framework, and then "Target myproject has copy command".

Comment: maybe you can post a screenshot with your xcode build settings although there are several places to check for. What about  running ns build ios in console? What errors do you get then?

Comment: IT WORKED. I don't know how, but I got it to build. So thank you for helping.

Comment: Glad you had it working! Life of a developer, trial and error plus fingers crossed :-)